Accessing FastText Library Directly from PHP Without Using Python
I want to access and use the FastText library directly from my PHP code without using Python or creating a web service (e.g., using Flask) to wrap the FastText functionality and call it from PHP. Is there a way to do this?
I tried Python, but I want to avoid using multiple programs. I'm using a Windows system and seeking direct access if possible.

You can execute shell commands from PHP and retrieve the results using exec or libraries like symfony/process
